# Additional content in custom web part header

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am attempting to insert some HTML into the header of a custom web part (next to the title in the ms-WPHeader div).

I have been unable to find any documentation or instructions and would appreciate the help.

Comment: if you doing this task without code then you use webpart properties for that. go to the webpart properties and in toolpane see the 'title' in Appearance part. you can modified that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint expects to be in control of the Crome around the WebPart content and has no option for you to specify HTML to go next to the Title. If you want to add commands which can be applied to the web part then SharePoint expects you to either add Verbs to the dropdown in the header or add a contextual tab to the ribbon.

But if you really want to add html in the header then you have to do it through JavaScript.